# How to document errors in graphql?

Tags: graphql

```
type Query {
    """
    ErrorCode: EMAIL_DUPLICATED

    type EmailDuplicatedError {
        email: String!
        source: UserSource!
    }        
    enum UserSource {
        Google
        Facebook
        Github
    }
    """
    register(email: String!, password: String!): AccessToken!
}

"""
The AccessToken scalar type is a string of 16 characters.
"""
scalar AccessToken
```

Hope you can get what I mean through the above schema. I'd like to know if there is any code generator can support errors documented this way, so I can reduce the code I write on both client and server side.

I don't want to define errors like the following

```
type Query {
    register(email: String!, password: String!): RegisterResponse
}

type RegisterResponse {
    accessToken: AccessToken
    error: EmailDuplicatedError
}
type EmailDuplicatedError {
    email: String!
    source: UserSource!
}        
enum UserSource {
    Google
    Facebook
    Github
}

"""
The AccessToken scalar type is a string of 16 characters.
"""
scalar AccessToken
```

Because I'd like errors to be responded in errors field, and api only shows what you can get when you succeeded.

Thank you for your time reading this post.

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#response  http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Errors-and-Non-Nullability

Answer (score 0):

There's some ways to do error handling with GraphQL, I'll recommend you two:

- Using response extensions:
  GraphQL JSON `response.error` has a field called `extensions`, you can use this to set a `code` field like:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "example",
        "extensions": {
          "code": "YOUR CODE"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- Using unions:
  There is an medium post by Sasha Solomon that talks about that:
  https://sachee.medium.com/200-ok-error-handling-in-graphql-7ec869aec9bc

Using the examples in this post, the way to handle graphql errors with unions is like this:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String
}

type Suspended {
  reason: String
}

type IsBlocked {
  message: String
  blockedByUser: User
}

type UnavailableInCountry {
  countryCode: Int
  message: String
}


"User, or reason we can't get one normally"
union UserResult = User | IsBlocked | Suspended

type Query {
  user: UserResult!
}
```

Comment: I'm using extensions.code now. The problem is I don't know how to document this in graphql, so front-end developers can know in advance which error they might encounter, so they can handle fail successfully.

Comment: I'd like to find a code generator which can generate typescript typings to facilitate development on both front- and back-end

Comment: As for the second method, it puts a burden on query, that's why I'd like to avoid it.